# Write Hex in C (byte)

Tags: c, hex, byte

I have to write a byte in hex to a file but I have a problem. For example.

If I have:

```
unsigned char a = 0x0;
```

and I write to a file using fwrite:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt",wb);
fwrite(&a,sizeof(unsigned char),1,fp);
fclose(fp);
```

When I open file I always see 20h, why not 00h?

So, I try to use:

```
fprintf(fp,"%x",a);
```

In this case I see 0h, but I need a full byte, not a nibble.
What should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to write a single zero byte to the file, or the ASCII string "00" or "00h"? Please clarify your intent.

Comment: Also, what tool do you use to inspect the content of the file? A hex editor?

Comment: @dvnrrs
I want to write 00h.

Comment: In that case `fprintf(fp, "%02xh", a);` is what you want (basically @unwind's answer but with an `h` at the end).

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I inspect with Notepad++, but I download a hex editor now and open the file with it and everything is ok... what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first example is hard to believe, it ought to generate a file with a single byte with the value 0 in it. That's not really a text file though, so I guess your tools might fool you.

The second attempt is better, assuming you want a text file with a text representation of the value in it. To make it two hexadecimal digits, specify a width and padding:

```
fprintf(fp, "%02x", a);
```

Please note that there is no such thing as "a hex value". A value is a value; it can be *represented* as hex, but that's not part of the value. 100 decimal is the same thing as 64 in hex, and 1100100 in binary. The base only matters when representing the number as a string of digits, the number itself can't "be hex".